# Is binary crossentropy the only loss function that can be paired with sigmoid when building a model for multi-label image classification?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multilabel-classification, conv-neural-network

I am using Keras to build a CNN to classify images from the fashion MNist dataset.

I have taken the 28x28 images and created new images by placing each image into one corner of a 56X56 image, i.e. a new image might be a shoe in the top left corner with the rest of the image being white, etc. 
Instead of just classifying the object in the image, I want it to also classify the position of the object in the image, with 14 classes in total - 10 for the type of object in the image and 4 for the position.

The labels are one hot encoded, so for instance, an image that has a bag in the bottom left corner would have the label [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0] the first 1 marking the object as a bag and the second 1 indicating it is in the lower left corner.

Everything I have read states that for multi-label classification, the final activation function should be sigmoid and the loss binary crossentropy.  I understand the reasoning for this, but is that the only viable combination?

I have tried many CNN architectures and hyperparameter searches, and the best validation accuracy I can achieve using binary crossentropy as the loss is around 0.50.

However, if I change the loss to categorical crossentropy, I am able to achieve around 0.85 validation accuracy and good predictions on unseen data.  However, it's not exactly what I want, as the 10 object classes should be independent from the 4 position classes, and ideally I want a probability for belonging to each class independently (not summed to 1).

Considering the type of task, would I be better building a model that has multiple outputs and multiple losses?

Comment: BCE is suppose to work with this as well, as I'm using it for most of multilabel task too.

Comment: Sounds you should have two separate softmax output layers instead: One with 10 units for the class and one with 4 units for the position, and use categorical cross-entropy (separately) as loss for both layers.

Comment: Thank you, @xdurch0.  That was my suspicion but being very new to keras I wanted to check that I wasn't missing something obvious.  Will try that and update if it worked.

Comment: If two sets of classes are completely independent, e.g. bags are not more likely to be in one corner, it might be more efficient to have two completely separate NNs. Otherwise any spurious correlation in the training data could hurt the final accuracy.